# iOS: Launch Image for all devices, include iPad Pro

Tags: ios, xcode, xcasset, launchimage

I followed the guidelines on making the static launch screen images.

[image]

Yet, then I added the images to the xcassets as LaunchImage

However, they did not fill in the asset as expected. There are warnings warn about I need to have screen sizes such as 2208x1242, etc. Where I can have all the sizes needed for an App?

[image]

Also, why there is no iPad Pro launch images? How can I add it? Thanks.

Comment: You should be using a launch screen storyboard, not launch images.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you drag an image into the launch image asset catalog, it will warn you that it's not the right dimensions, and will tell you what the dimensions should be. From that you can conclude:

```
iPhone Portrait iOS 5,6@1x: 320x480
iPhone Portrait iOS 5,6@2x: 640x960
iPhone Portrait iOS 5,6@Retina 4: 640x1136

iPad Portrait Without Status Bar iOS 5,6@1x: 768x1004
iPad Portrait Without Status Bar iOS 5,6@2x: 1536x2008

iPad Portrait iOS 5,6@1x: 768x1024
iPad Portrait iOS 5,6@2x: 1536x2048

iPad Landscape Without Status Bar iOS 5,6@1x: 1024x748
iPad Landscape Without Status Bar iOS 5,6@2x: 2048x1496

iPad Landscape iOS 5,6@1x: 1024x768
iPad Landscape iOS 5,6@2x: 2048x1536

iPhone Portrait iOS 8,9@Retina HD 5.5: 1242x2208
iPhone Portrait iOS 8,9@Retina HD 4.7: 750x1334

iPhone Landscape iOS 8,9@Retina HD 5.5: 2208x1242

12.9-inch iPad Pro Portrait: 2048x2732
12.9-inch iPad Pro Landscape: 2732x2048

iPhone Portrait iOS 7-9@2x: 640x960
iPhone Portrait iOS 7-9@Retina 4: 640x1136

iPad Portrait iOS 7-9@1x: 768x1024
iPad Portrait iOS 7-9@2x: 1536x2048

iPad Landscape iOS 7-9@1x: 1024x768
iPad Landscape iOS 7-9@2x: 2048x1536

iPhone X Portrait iOS 11+: 1125×2436
iPhone X Landscape iOS 11+: 2436x1125
```

Note, it wouldn't give me the dimensions for the 12" iPad, so I got that from the [iOS Human Interface Guidelines - Launch Screen](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/graphics/launch-screen/) which you included in your question.

Comment: Thanks for this...not only a great resource for the image sizes, but a 'Teach a man to fish...' answer as well!

Answer (score 8):

Updated image with asset dimensions annotated :

[image: LaunchImage asset dimensions]

Comment: Thanks for the sizes. It really helped.

Answer (score 5):

To anyone reading this and is giving up hope on adding old style Launch Images for **iPad Pro 10.5 inch,  11 inch and 12.9 inch**, you can add them *without* using the Storyboard or Launch Screen thing in XCode.

The way we did it was by editing the .plist of our app:

```
<key>UILaunchImages</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
        <string>7.0</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
        <string>Default-Portrait</string> //iPad Pro 10.5"
        <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
        <string>Portrait</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
        <string>{768, 1024}</string>
    </dict>
    <dict> 
        <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
        <string>12.0</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
        <string>Default-Portrait-1194h</string> //iPad Pro 11"
        <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
        <string>Portrait</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
        <string>{834, 1194}</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
        <string>9.0</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
        <string>Default-Portrait-iPadPro</string>//iPad Pro 12"
        <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
        <string>Portrait</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
        <string>{1024, 1366}</string>
    </dict>
</array>
```

(Be sure to remove the //iPad Pro comments obviously!)

And here are the filenames:

**iPad Pro 10.5":**
Default-Portrait@2x~ipad

**iPad Pro 11":**
Default-Portrait-1194h@2x.png

**iPad Pro 12":**
Default-Portrait-iPadPro@2x~ipad

Tested on all 3 of those devices and it works.

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: if you are still active... do you know in which directory i have to put the files

Answer (score 1):

In Assets.xcassets click + button -> App Icons & Launch Images -> New iOS Launch Image

[image]

Comment: Ugh, I'm blind. Xcode 7 didn't support it and I even tried it in Xcode 8 before seeing your answer and didn't notice the iPad Pro entry right there in the middle.

Comment: Yes, I can get this, but I found that I do no know the exact size of 1x iOS7-9 iPad Landscape, I do not know exactly the dimension of the images to be filled in these boxes... Any one can help?

Comment: I am not seeing a placeholder for iPad Pro 12.9 when I follow above steps. Xcode 8.3.2. Anything I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

Launch Screens should probably be taken care of by Storyboards rather than static images. However the Launch Screens aren't included in your Main.storyboard file. That way, Xcode will resize everything as expected with Auto Layout and you don't have to fill your app with tons of image files. So it'll work with the iPad Pro sizes 9.7" *2048 x 1536px* and 12.9", *2732 x 2048px*.

In Xcode, go to
**File** > **New File** > **Launch Screen** (Under the User Interface header) > then all the usual location and target adding bits.

[Creating a new Launch Image file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMQrP.jpg)

Edit it like you would in Interface Builder. As far as I'm aware, you can't assign a Class to it so don't expect any animations.

[Xcode showing the Launch Screen in Interface Builder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4EMH.jpg)

Comment: So that means I cannot use Launch Image any more starting from now? In the past, I just include Launch Image in my app and everything was fine...

Comment: You can still use Launch Images if you'd prefer! Apple added these Launch Screens as an alternative if you wanted to use Auto Layout over generating static content.